# How about use Face Recognition?

Tags: python, face-recognition

I am using Face Recognition. When I load a folder and choose an image of the person, after that the script will find all images associated with that person and delete them. But when I run the code it deletes all the pictures with faces.

CODE 1:

```
def load_file(self):
    filename = askopenfilename()
    self._file_field.delete(0, tk.END)  # deletes the current value
    self._file_field.insert(0, filename)
    for widget in self._image_panel.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    panel = tk.Label(self._image_panel, image=img)
    panel.img = img
    panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
```

CODE 2:

```
def load_folder(self):
    filename = askdirectory()
    self._folder_field.delete(0, tk.END)  # deletes the current value
    self._folder_field.insert(0, filename)
```

CODE 3:

```
def start_process(self):
    ref_path = self._file_field.get()
    folder_path = self._folder_field.get()
    self.find_and_delete(folder_path, ref_path)
```

CODE 4:

```
def run_process(self):
    self._run_task = True
    t = Thread(target=self.start_process)
    t.start()
```

CODE 5:

```
def find_and_delete(self, directory, ref_image_path):
    ref_face = self.get_ref_face(ref_image_path)
    if ref_face is None:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Can't find a face. Reference Image quality is not enough")
        return
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    i = 1
    for filename in files:
        try:
            percentage = int((i / len(files)) * 100)
            self._progress['value'] = percentage
            self.update_idletasks()
            i += 1
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            if self.is_user_in_image(ref_face, file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(filename, 'deleted.')
        except:
            print('Error reading file', filename)
    messagebox.showinfo("Information", "Process Finished")
```

CODE 6

```
def get_ref_face(self, ref_image_path):
    try:
        ref_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(ref_image_path)
        ref_face = face_recognition.face_encodings(ref_image)[0]
        return ref_face
    except:
        return None
```

CODE 7:

```
def is_user_in_image(self, ref_face, image_path):
    unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_path)
    unknown_faces = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)

    for unknown_face in unknown_faces:
        results = face_recognition.compare_faces([ref_face], unknown_face)
        if results[0]:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: You can't merely post a bunch if code snippets, say they don't do something right, and expect anyone to be able to help you. You need to post a runnable [mre] and specify exactly what's wrong with it, show any error message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's realy hard to understand what and when your code fragments are doing but it is possible that your CODE 7 recognizes everyone as similar enougth ones  with default tolerance.
Try something like that

```
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([ref_face], unknown_face, tolerance=0.15)
```

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks you so much bro! But when i use tkiner, error reading file!

Comment: File reading error is definitely unlinked to the face recognition pipeline. Watch what your app doing at every step.

Comment: I want send to you my code. Could you help me fix it?